# How to create pdf document in uwp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp-xaml

I searched how to create a pdf document with universal Windows plateform.

I've been looking for solutions and i found this but it doesn't work at all:

```
 string path = "test.pdf";
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

 PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
 PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();
 using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
 {
     //Add a page in the PDF document.
     PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
     //Access the PDF graphics instance of the page.
     PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;
     //Create the PDF font instance.
     PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.TimesRoman, 15);
     //Draw the text in PDF page.
     graphics.DrawString("Hello world!", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new PointF(20, 20));
     //Save the PDF document to disk
     pdf.Save(stream);
}
```

Thanks for reading me

Error pdf.Save(stream): System.NotSupportedException : 'Memory stream is not expandable.'

Comment: What you are getting error ?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException : 'Memory stream is not expandable.'

Comment: I've added Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable NuGet and using Syncfusion.Drawing;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;

Comment: If you want to save the PDF to disk, why do you use a `MemoryStream` and not a `FileStream`? And if you want to actually save a variable size PDF into a `MemoryStream`, why do you initialize the `MemoryStream` with a very small fixed buffer? Your code makes no sense.